# Amazon Ec2: Issue with Setting up FTP Server

Tags: amazon-ec2, ftp, vsftpd

after setting up My vsFtp Server ON Ec2 i am facing problem , my client is Filezilla

and i am getting this error

```
Response:   230 Login successful.
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 Always in UTF8 mode.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/"
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   500 OOPS: invalid pasv_address
Command:    PORT 10,130,8,44,240,50
Response:   500 OOPS: priv_sock_get_cmd
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Error:  Connection closed by server
```

this is the current setting in my **vsftpd.conf**

```
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure                                                                                                                          
#async_abor_enable=YES                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
# ASCII mangling is a horrible feature of the protocol.                                                                                         
#ascii_upload_enable=YES                                                                                                                        
#ascii_download_enable=YES                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
# You may specify a file of disallowed anonymous e-mail addresses. Apparently                                                                   
# useful for combatting certain DoS attacks.                                                                                                    
#deny_email_enable=YES                                                                                                                          
# (default follows)                                                                                                                             
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd/banned_emails                                                                                                    
#                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
chroot_local_user=YES                                                                                                                           
#chroot_list_enable=YES                                                                                                                         
# (default follows)                                                                                                                             
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list                                                                                                       
  GNU nano 2.0.6                               File: /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf                                                                    

#                                                                                                                                                               #ls_recurse_enable=YES                                                                                                                          
#                                                                                          
# When "listen" directive is enabled, vsftpd runs in standalone mode and                                                                        
# listens on IPv4 sockets. This directive cannot be used in conjunction                                                                         
# with the listen_ipv6 directive.                                                                                                               
listen=YES                                                                                                                                      
#                                                                                                                                               
# This directive enables listening on IPv6 sockets. To listen on IPv4 and IPv6                                                                  
# sockets, you must run two copies of vsftpd with two configuration files.                                                                      
# Make sure, that one of the listen options is commented !!                                                                                     
#listen_ipv6=YES                                                                                                                                
pam_service_name=vsftpd                                                                                                                         
userlist_enable=YES                                                                                                                             
tcp_wrappers=YES                                                                                                                                
pasv_enable=YES                                                                                                                                 
pasv_min_port=2345                                                                                                                              
pasv_max_port=2355                                                                                                                              
listen_port=1024                                                                                                                                
pasv_address=ec2-xxxxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com                                                                                           
pasv_promiscuous=YES
```

Note: i have already open those port in security group 
      i mean listen port, min max

if someone shows me how to fix this i will be very greatful
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either `pasv_address` needs to be the external IP address, or `pasv_addr_resolve=YES` needs to be set so that the hostname you entered will be resolved when vsftpd starts.  If you use a hostname with pasv_addr_resolve, vsftpd has to be restarted if the IP address changes.

Comment: I just set my FTP client to use Passive Mode by default, but this should fix it on the server end of things.

Comment: It's the server end of things that's wrong, that's why the server fails to go into PASV mode `500 OOPS: invalid pasv_address`

Answer (score 1):

pasv_address= IP address

you need an Elastic IP